# Parametros para consulta em query no sql server

Tags: sql-server

Bom dia..

Tenho uma query no sql server com colunas de data e estado, preciso trazer o resultado pela data digitada ou pelo estado digitado ou pelos dois, como posso fazer isso direito na query no sql server. Ex se o usuário digita somente a data de inicio e final trazer o resultado, e se o usuário também digitar o estado também trazer o resultado pela data digitada e também pelo estado seleccionado.

segue minha query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CONCAT(SA1.A1_COD, ' - ', SA1.A1_NOME) AS CLIENTE,
SA3.A3_NOME                            AS VENDEDOR, 
SD2.D2_EST                             AS ESTADO,
SUM(CAST(SD2.D2_QUANT AS DECIMAL(18,2)))                      AS QTDA, 
SUM(SD2.D2_TOTAL)                      AS [TOTAL SEM IPI], 
SUM(SD2.D2_VALBRUT)                    AS [TOTAL COM IPI]
FROM SD2010 AS SD2 
INNER JOIN SA1010 AS SA1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SA1.A1_COD = SD2.D2_CLIENTE 
INNER JOIN SB1010 AS SB1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SB1.B1_COD = SD2.D2_COD
INNER JOIN SC5010 AS SC5 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SC5.C5_NUM = SD2.D2_PEDIDO
INNER JOIN SA3010 AS SA3 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SA3.A3_COD = SC5.C5_VEND1
WHERE SD2.D2_TES IN ('501', '502', '505', '506', '507', '509', '513', '514', 
'518', '591', '592', '594', '596', '597', '603', '604', '606', '607')
AND SD2.D2_EMISSAO BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '08/01/2018' , 103) AND 
CONVERT(datetime, '08/01/2018' , 103) 
AND SA1.A1_FILIAL IN ('01', '') 
AND SD2.D2_FILIAL IN ('01', '') 
AND SB1.B1_FILIAL IN ('01', '')
AND SD2.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
AND SA1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
GROUP BY SA1.A1_COD, SA1.A1_NOME, SA3.A3_NOME, SD2.D2_EST
ORDER BY [TOTAL COM IPI] DESC
```

Comment: Pode fazer isso por uma Stored Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer a comparação se o parâmetro é nulo e usar operador `OR` caso não seja, se fosse "dizer" a lógica seria assim:

> "parâmetro @datainicial é nulou ou a D2_EMISSAO = @datainicial"

Claro, o seu caso usando `BETWEEN`, e o mesmo para o estado:

```
WHERE .... 
AND 
( 
  ( 
    @DATAINI IS NULL 
    AND 
    @DATAFIM IS NULL 
  ) 
  OR 
  ( 
    sd2.d2_emissao BETWEEN 
    CONVERT(datetime, @DATAINI , 103) 
    AND 
    CONVERT(datetime, @DATAFIM , 103) 
  ) 
) 
) 
AND 
( 
  @ESTADO IS NULL 
  OR 
  campo_estado = @ESTADO 
)
```

Ou seja, ou as datas são nulas (não passou o parâmetros) ou compara.
Ou o estado é nulo (não passou) ou compara.

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certo aqui vlw